# How can i change the width and the height size of the div class "col-sm-9"?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to set the  to custom size, but in css the height command is not working…
How can i set to custom size?
I need this to my image slider, but the col-sm-10 is too high in my website.
Waiting for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To change the height of the carousel you have to use 'vh' like this:

```
.carousel {
    width: 100vh; // if you want 100% of the height, or what you want for the height
}
```